# 3rd party JSON into ArcGIS Operations Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-server, json, operations-dashboard, arcgis-enterprise

I have a 3rd party JSON response of coordinates and attributes coming from SQL Server via WebMethods and want to get it into an ArcGIS Operations Dashboard.
I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do this.

I can break it apart and get the coordinates to put it into an ArcGIS JavaScript web map, but was hoping to use Operations Dashboard for some of the UI and charting functionality.

This is a simplified version of what the response looks like:

```
{"records":[{"ID":1,"X_COORD":"50","Y_COORD":"50"},{"ID":2,"X_COORD":"60","Y_COORD":"60"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The OpsDashboard does take URL Params (https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/ops-dashboard/decision-support/make-your-dashboards-more-dynamic-using-url-parameters/) such as zooming to a coordinate extent.

You sound like you have a list of Coords you want visualised in the dashboard?
Might be possible to munge your response into a featureCollection and hijack the  contents of the WebMap within the OpsDashboard (https://developers.arcgis.com/web-map-specification/objects/featureCollection/)

However, I would recommend looking at a back-end process that takes your JSON, converts it into a FeatureCollection JSON and [appends](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/append-feature-service-layer-.htm) it into a dedicated feature layer that is used downstream in the OpsDasboard.  The Append endpoint on a FeatureLayer accepts featureCollection JSON via the Edits param.